# Esp8266 DHT11 Humidity & Temperature but Failed to read from DHT sensor

Tags: arduino-esp8266, blynk

Help please
I'm trying to get the sensor values from DHT11 Humidity & Temperature Sensor but the Esp8266 is connecting to internet but is not reading the value from the sensor.

I'm using Blynk to display the sensor value

```js
this is what appears in my monitors Serial

21:41:24.811 -> �����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������[24759] Connected to WiFi
21:41:26.726 -> [24759] IP: 192.168.1.9
21:41:26.760 -> [24759] 
21:41:26.760 -> ___ __ __
21:41:26.796 -> / _ )/ /_ _____ / /__
21:41:26.796 -> / _ / / // / _ \/ '_/
21:41:26.832 -> /____/_/\_, /_//_/_/\_\
21:41:26.865 -> /___/ v0.5.4 on NodeMCU
21:41:26.903 -> 
21:41:26.903 -> [24837] Connecting to blynk-cloud.com:80
21:41:30.876 -> [28951] Ready (ping: 23ms).
21:41:34.230 -> Failed to read from DHT sensor!
21:41:34.940 -> Failed to read from DHT sensor!
21:42:56.217 -> Failed to read from DHT sensor!
```

[my code](https://github.com/unmalnickname/esp8266_Blynk_DHT11/blob/master/sketch_dec30b.ino)

[my current circuit diagram](http:///http://prntscr.com/m4pvss)

Comment: You have to show your code otherwise it's impossible to help you just by reading your serial output

Comment: this is my code https://github.com/unmalnickname/esp8266_Blynk_DHT11/blob/master/sketch_dec30b.ino

Comment: my current circuit diagram http://prntscr.com/m4pvss

Comment: You should put a 10K resistor from pin 2 (data) to pin 1 (power) of the sensor

Comment: Your diagram shows it's connected to D4, but in your code it's D2.

Answer (score 0):

- Double check the connection of sensor and its variable define in code, it has to be the same, most projects with esp use D4 for dht input.
- Try to put  4k7 to 10k resistor between +VCC and dht's data out pin.